# If code structure

Tags: java, if-statement

I know basic if statement structure, but this confuses me

```
public void setHandleName(String handle){
    if(handle.length() < 10){
        return;
    }

    handleName = handle;
}
```

It returns the value when the handle.length() is bigger than 10, isn't it supposed to be returning the value when handle.length() is less than 10?

Why does this if statement does the opposite?

```
if(false){ //do stuff； }
```

Where the if statement should be

```
if(true){ //do stuff; }
```

Sorry for the vague explanation, english is not my native language.
Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Your method has a return type of **void**, so it's not returning anything, under any circumstances.  It is conditionally updating `handleName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> It returns the value when the handle.length() is bigger than 10

No it doesn't. It never returns any value, the method is of type `void`. It does **set** the `handleName` instance field if the name is at least 10 characters long (and not set it if the name is less than 10 characters long).

> , isn't it supposed to be returning the value when handle.length() is less than 10?

No, the `if` clearly says "If the length of handle is less than 10, return" and that's *before* it sets `handleName`. `return` leaves the function right away, bypassing any code that may follow.

> Why does this if statement does the opposite?
>
> ```
> if(false){ //do stuff； }
> ```

Because in that case, the logic is *within* the `if` block; in your first example, it's *after* an `if` block that `return`s early (bypassing the remainder of the function). That is, your first example is:

```
if (!condition) {
    return;
}
doSomething();
```

but your second example is

```
if (condition) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Here's an annotated version of your first example:

```
public void setHandleName(String handle){ // Accept a `handle` string parameter
    if(handle.length() < 10){             // If the length of `handle` is less
                                          // than 10, enter the block
        return;                           // Leave this method immediately, without
                                          // doing anything else
    }                                     // This is the end of the conditional bit

    handleName = handle;                  // Set `handleName` to `handle`
}
```

So if we go into the `if` block, we'll return, and never reach the `handleName = handle;` line, so we never set it. If we *don't* go into the `if` block, we don't return early, so we *do* set it.

We can (and probably should) rewrite `setHandleName` to use the structure from your later examples:

```
public void setHandleName(String handle){ // Accept a `handle` string parameter
    if(handle.length() >= 10){            // If `handle`'s length is 10 or higher
        handleName = handle;              // Set `handleName` to `handle`
    }                                     // This is the end of the conditional bit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return anything (as the `void` return type indicates). It **sets** the value of `handleName` to `handle`, but only if `handle.length()` is greater or equal to 10. If `handle.length()` is less than 10 it will just `return` from the method without doing anything more.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to note:

- The return type on this method is `void`. This means that it doesn't have a value to return.  You can absolutely use `return` in a void method, but that implies...
- This method **returns early** based on a condition.  Effectively, if the value doesn't satisfy a specific criteria, it silently ignores what was passed into it.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make it clearer what the code is actually doing?

```
public void setHandleName(String handle){
    if(handle.length() >= 10){
        handleName = handle;
    }
    // otherwise handleName is not set, and the method exits
    // nothing is returned because the method is 'void'
}
```

Please note that `if(false){ //do stuff； }` will **never** "do stuff"